# Superimposing AC signal and DC signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain-bandwidth-product

I am trying to add a sinusoidal signal to the positive and negative rails of an op-amp under test, and change the frequency and amplitude of this sine wave to test the CMRR and PSRR. I need to superimpose an AC and DC signal. I have found two circuits for this purpose.

1. Using a current feedback amplifier and doing so as stated in [this application note.](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa414a/slaa414a.pdf?ts=1708922339231&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#:%7E:text=In%20the%20case%20of%20LDOs,expressed%20in%20decibels%20(dB).)
2. In case I don't feel comfortable with a current feedback amplifier, can I use the configuration below?

[image: schematic 1]

I need to sweep the frequency from 1 KHz - 20 MHz with a 1 V p-p amplitude for the sine wave.

Does what I have put before C2 add sine wave extra? Does the second configuration work at all with a fixed inductor?

I see some spikes in the output. When I increase the inductance they go away.  Why is that?

[image]

Comment: You have to flip vertically Q3.

Comment: Another tip: Your problem ("superimposing ac signal and DC signal") is solved in the biasing circuits of AC amplifiers. You can use the same idea here.

Comment: According to what I said above, I think that the AC+DC output of your circuits is the midpoint between C2 and L2.

Answer (score 2):

Your PNP transistor is incorrectly wired for best operation. With it wired the way you have shown, it will still work but the beta will be about one-tenth of the normal value for beta: -

[image]

I expect that once you fix that it will be improved but, take note; the next problem will be cross-over distortion as the input sinewave frequency rises. If I were you I'd dispense with BJTs and find an op-amp with more grunt-power.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do it, the old fashioned way - a transformer driven by a signal source and the DC going through the secondary.

You can use something like a 600\$\Omega\$ line transformer, either with dual secondaries or two single secondary transformers with their primaries in series.

You can set it up with the AC signals in phase on the output, or reverse one secondary to have them out of phase.

Here's one possible arrangement:
[image: AC imposed on DC through transformer]

C1 and R3 are there to make the simulation work (LTspice doesn't like things having no path to ground or voltage sources DC shorted), you'd have to come up with a suitable way of connecting the primary to your particular signal source.

Comment: Not all transformers will tolerate much of a DC bias current. Some audio transformers often tolerate some, but the OP wants AC up to MHz. RF transformers generally have such low DC resistance, that they will not tolerate much DC bias current. Bias-T network would be better.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yeah, I somehow missed the 20 MHz part,even after looking to see if there was a frequency range specified in the question, not sure what happened there.

I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

## Understanding unfamiliar circuits

The OP put us in a bit of an awkward situation by presenting us with a completely unfamiliar circuit without any explanation... then disappeared. So the problem is entirely ours :-)

But I think that is exactly the "charm" of the situation we are in because times have changed, and formal textbook explanations through banal verbal clichés do not work in such cases. We already have a competitor - AI, and we have to show that we are at least somehow superior to it. That thing is *understanding unfamiliar circuits*.

We (and OP, I hope) need to develop a set of universal methods of understanding circuits that we can apply in the future when we find ourselves in a similar situation. This is much more valuable than a specific explanation because we can explain many specific circuits through it.

## How to do it

I suggest the following procedures:

- Seeking to recognize familiar circuit building (functional) blocks and devices.
- Replacing them with equivalent simpler electrical elements (AC sources).
- Replacing the AC input voltage sources with DC ones, and exploring the circuit for zero, positive and negative voltage.
- Transferring the results to the real circuit.

Usually, this is done in the reverse order (circuit degradation by "reverse engineering") but for our purposes here I suggest building the circuit. Let's start from the very beginning.

## The problem

What we do know is that the OP wants to add 1 V AC voltage to the supply voltages. It is not difficult to guess that such a problem is solved in bias circuits, only that there the AC signal is usually shifted to the middle of the supply voltage, and here all the way to the supply rails.

So we should be looking to see something like a bias circuit where two voltage sources - AC and DC, are connected in series.

## Building the circuit

**Producing a sine wave (Vin):** The first thing we recognize on the left side of the schematic is an AC sine voltage source (V5) buffered with an op-amp (U1) and push-pull (Q2 and Q3) voltage follower. For the purposes of our conceptual simulation, we can represent it only by a function generator symbol Vin from the CircuitLab library (it can provide unlimited current because it is ideal).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOBOUe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Its voltage "wiggles" with an amplitude of 1 V relative to the zero voltage level (ground).

[image: STEP 1.1]

**Adding a "shifting" voltage (C):** On the right we see a capacitor (C2) in series which is obviously charged to the voltage (10 V) of the power supply (V3). For now, this is just a guess, but we will check it later. Aha... there it is adding voltage (10 V), just like in the bias circuits of AC amplifiers!

We know that a charged capacitor with a sufficiently large capacitance behaves as a voltage source. Then let's represent it with a constant voltage source (figuratively labeled C) from the CircuitLab library.

For completeness, let's also add a 1kΩ load (RL), although it will not have any effect on the circuit since the sources are ideal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQxZ1n.png)</sup>

Our assumptions have come true - the sum of the two voltages appears across the load (or the input voltage is "shifted up" by 10V before being applied to the load).

[image: STEP 1.2]

**Charging the capacitor:** We continue to examine the OP's circuit and see that an inductor (L2) is connected in series with the capacitor (C2).

We also know that a charged inductor with a sufficiently large inductance behaves as a current source. Then let's represent it with a constant current source (figuratively labeled L) from the CircuitLab library. What is its role here?

Aha... the actual capacitor must be charged in some way, i.e. we need a power supply. However, it cannot be a constant voltage source because the voltage across the Vin-C circuit varies, and the current will become unacceptably high (a conflict between the voltage sources will appear). So this should be a current source at best.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feipAB.png)</sup>

The current source passes its current through both voltage sources but this does not change anything.

[image: STEP 1.3]

**Adding a power supply:** Looking at the OP's schematic, we finally see a voltage source (V3). Why do we need it after we have a current source?

Oh, clear... The real inductor does not contain an internal voltage source so it is gradually exhausting. To keep it charged, there is a need of a 10 V power supply V+.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYyVJ3.png)</sup>

Now we see how the load voltage changes with an amplitude of 1 V with respect to V+.

[image: STEP 1.4]

**Doubling the circuit:** Now we just need to do the same for the negative power supply and to connect the op-amp (device under test). Both halves can be driven from the same input source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6H1W.png)</sup>

We see that the input voltage is "shifted" to the positive and negative supply rails of the op-amp.

[image: STEP 1.5]

**Real circuit:** Finally, we replace the equivalent electrical elements (current and voltage sources) with real ones (inductors and capacitors).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23V3V.png)</sup>

The voltage graphs are the same.

[image: STEP 1.6]

The task is accomplished, the idea behind the OP's circuit is unraveled.

## Exploring in depth

If we want to understand the circuit even better, we can go down to an even lower level by replacing the input AC voltage source with a constant DC voltage source with three typical voltage values ​​- 0 V, 1 V and -1 V. We can also replace the load resistor with a voltmeter with the same 1 kΩ internal resistance RL= 1k.

Our main goal is to trace where the currents flow and mark them with arrows in green (to see the current magnitudes, hover the mouse over the circuit elements). As you can see, regardless of whether...

**Vin = 0 V:** ... the input voltage is 0...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwjwQH.png)</sup>

**Vin = 1 V:** ... positive...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY4Sue.png)</sup>

**Vin = -1 V:** ... or negative...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcFy8p.png)</sup>

... the pattern of currents does not change.